# On words related to commone root: awe

Tags: roots

My question is: How come the three words "awesome," "awe," and "awe-inspiring" denote positivism with the root awe, they are virtuous too,but the 4th word "awful" denotes negativity.
Even the spelling of "awe" gets pruned to "aw", as if the "e" of "awe" chewed up the virtues of "awe" like a rat and ran away with them. It leaves me clueless. Hope you help me locate the rat.

Comment: It's good to do research, but when you quote a dictionary entry you need to put quote marks around it, and properly cite it by telling us the name of the dictionary it came from. For now, I have edited your post to remove the dictionary entries; please add the name of the source when you edit it to add them back in.

Comment: I agree, it does seem to be a duplicate.